# Problem removing multiple objects from NSMutableArray iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I am having trouble removing objects from nsmutable array.  Here it is.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.lockerz.com/dailies"]];
NSData *datadata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];  
NSString *removeForArray = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:datadata encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSArray *theArray = [removeForArray componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];  
NSMutableArray *deArray = [[NSMutableArray array] initWithArray:theArray];
[deArray removeObjectsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 40)];  
NSLog(@"%@", deArray);
```

Comment: It crashes on me and says the following:


*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray initWithCapacity:]: method only defined for abstract class.  Define -[__NSArrayM initWithCapacity:]!'
*** Call stack at first throw:

Comment: Michael Amici: You seem to have confused `alloc` (which returns a blank object you own which you then need to initialize) with `array` (which returns an initialized empty array object you don't own). See Georg Fritzsche's answer for one solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+[NSMutableArray array]` already returns an initialized array. Don't use an initializer method on that, they are used on new instances that you `alloc`d.

In this case you can either

- `alloc`/`init` an instance
- use `-mutableCopy`
- use a suitable convenience constructor

The three following lines are equivalent:

```
NSMutableArray *a = [[theArray mutableCopy] autorelease];
NSMutableArray *b = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:theArray];
NSMutableArray *c = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:theArray] autorelease];
```